# Android: how to properly use list items provided by the platform?

Tags: android, listview

On this page: Is given on this page: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html.  , the below tip is given.

> Tip: You can use list item designs
>   provided by the platform instead of
>   defining your own layout file for the
>   ListAdapter. For example, try using
>   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
>   instead of R.layout.list_item.

However, is it safe to use "simple_list_item_1"?  Is it guaranteed that all platforms will provide a list item with this id?

Comment: Any manufacturer that decides to ship Android devices will, most likely, want to be compatible with as many apps as possible. Thus, they do not have any reason to take out something that is given to them :)

Comment: @Felix, I'm still not convinced that this actually has to do with the layouts on the device itself. Wouldn't these be included in the apk at build time?

Comment: No. Any `android.R.*` references link to platform-specific resources. For example, if you use `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add`, it will be different on a vanilla Android device (Nexus *) versus an HTC Sense device. Actually, it will even be different between Google phones running different OS versions.

Comment: this is what i was concerned about.  but i accept it is an expected practice for manufacturers to not remove these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - yes, apparently these are bundled with Android and they should be supported on all platforms.

<strike>In any case, I believe what happens is that they are copied from the SDK into your project when you reference them.</strike>

As Felix pointed out, they are included on the device itself and they are considered to be part of the API.

You can see layouts available within the SDK on the Android [gitweb](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/layout;h=3c81d0a9f3cf1b966ef7e8a8c590bc6a604a944f;hb=refs/heads/master). For example, [simple_list_item_1.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml;h=c9c77a5f9c113a9d331d5e11a6016aaa815ec771;hb=refs/heads/master).

Answer (score 1):

Those layouts part of the SDK and should be included on all devices.